# retrieving data from sql database using C# with stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Whenever I try to retrieve data from my database i keep getting null. The code i'm using is below:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spSelectCustomer", myConnection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    myConnection.Open();

    SqlParameter custId = cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerId", SqlDbType.Int);
    custId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    custId.Value = 10;

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    Label1.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
    Label2.Text = dr["LastName"].ToString();
    Label3.Text = dr[3].ToString();
    Label4.Text = dr["Email"].ToString();
}
private static string GetConnectionString()
{
    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Lab3ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call `Read` before you can access data, Your code should be

```
While (dr.Read())
{

    Label1.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
    Label2.Text = dr["LastName"].ToString();
    Label3.Text = dr[3].ToString();
    Label4.Text = dr["Email"].ToString();
}

//close DataReader
dr.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you read column values from DataReader you must invoke [Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) method from data reader.

```
if (dr.Read())
{
    Label1.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
    Label2.Text = dr["LastName"].ToString();
    Label3.Text = dr[3].ToString();
    Label4.Text = dr["Email"].ToString();
}
```

You can also try:

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a call to `Read()` on your reader. I also suggest you wrap your `IDisposable` objects in `using` statements as below.

You also seem to be using a strange combination of column names and ordinal positions when retrieving your values from the `SqlDataReader`.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spSelectCustomer", myConnection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myConnection.Open();

            SqlParameter custId = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", 10);

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    Label1.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
                    Label2.Text = dr["LastName"].ToString();
                    Label3.Text = dr[3].ToString();
                    Label4.Text = dr["Email"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
while(myReader.Read()) 
{
Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(0));
}
myReader.Close();
//Implicitly closes the connection because CommandBehavior.CloseConnection was specified.
```

Documentation: [SqlCommand.ExecuteReader Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#overloads)